# How to add snippet menu onTrigger sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

I try to make in my snippet when you trigger it gives you the same "dropdown" as auto complete does.

My currently snippet looks like:

```
<snippet>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[
Somehow to make an menu..
        ]]>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>Trigger</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible. You'll need to write a plugin for this.